# how to play any video in html video tag

Tags: html, codeigniter, html5-video

I have a problem with html video tag..

I uploaded different types of video in to the db. when i was displaying in the front end they can't be playing. only plays the mp4 format videos.

How can i play all type of videos in one html video tag format.

I used the following ways to play the videos but i failed please help me

first formate

```
<video width="320" height="240" id="<?php  echo 'video'.$c_video ;?>" controls autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="<?php echo $path.'/'.$name ;?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="<?php echo $path.'/'.$nameogg ;?>" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
<!--  <source src="<?php echo $path.'/'.$namewebm ;?>" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'> -->
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Second Format

```
<object id="ie_plugin" classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616" width="660" height="300" codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab"> 
<param name="custommode" value="stage6" />
<param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
<param name="src" value="Cadbury.flv" />
<param name="bannerEnabled" value="false" />
<embed id="np_plugin" type="video/divx" src="link-to-avi" custommode="stage6" width="660" height="300" autoPlay="false" bannerEnabled="false" pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/">
</embed>
</object>
```

when this code using it asks plugin permission 
how can i solve with out asking permission and play any video in html tag 
or

any advise give to play any video in particular tag

please help me

Comment: second format
<object id="ie_plugin" classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616" width="660" height="300" codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab"> 
<param name="custommode" value="stage6" />
<param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
<param name="src" value="Cadbury.flv" />
<param name="bannerEnabled" value="false" />

Comment: <embed id="np_plugin" type="video/divx" src="link-to-avi" custommode="stage6" width="660" height="300" autoPlay="false" bannerEnabled="false" pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/">
</embed>
</object>

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding code to the comment section

Comment: And why do you want to display the same video of another type?

Comment: Yes i want to play any video in the same video tag...

Comment: But if the mp4 works in Chrome, why is there the need to make it work as an ogg or avi or something?

Comment: And not every browser can view every type of video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't embed other video formats in webpages using html video tag except mp4,ogg and webm. The solution is just convert your videos to mp4 format using ffmpeg.

Use this command to convert videos to mp4 without loosing quality:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i $video_flv -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -strict experimental $video_mp4');
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 there is the  tag, as you have in your first format. I should use that one. And because not every browser supports every video file type, you should convert every video to multiple file types. So you have a video named: Krishna. To support multiple browsers, you should convert this video. So you have Krishna.mp4, Krishna.ogg, Krishna.avi. And if you have another video, you also convert that video to multiple type files.

Here is more info http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: i want to play different type of videos in the same video tag in html.

Comment: Why? what is the use for that?

Comment: i upload different type of videos and those can play in the same tag one after one by a column wise.........

i wrote this code but the videos can't played otherthan mp4

Comment: so you don't want to see a different type, you want to see a whole new video

Comment: i cant get your question

Comment: in your question you have one video names: krishna, and this video has two different types, mp4 and ogg. You are talking about the video type (ogg, mp4) but you mean a whole new video, like krishna1

Comment: i just modified my question 
once check it out

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play all video format in html video tag when you use, you can face so many problem Browser problem, Os problem, video format, instead of you can convert all video format to mp4.

```
 https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html
```

FFmpeg server has so many option for video...

Comment: I used
exec("ffmpeg32 -i ".$video_name." -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k ".$video_name.".mp4") or die ("ffmpeg did not work");

this syntax to convert the videos in to mp4 when i'm uploading 
But it's not working to convert.....
is their any library to add the over come conversion problem

Comment: you need to install ffmpeg server Check phpinfo() function

Comment: Yeah!!
Obviously i installed the ffmpeg install in windows...
But how can i run in PHP codeigniter is their any library to run the ffmpeg command execution

Comment: no need to add any library. you should use exec or shell_exec  comment line execute